# Find all components at a specific location in swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm currently trying to add collision detection to my Java game.

Here is an example of what I tried to do :

```
public class Player extends JLabel {
    
    public String Name;
    public ImageIcon Image;
    public float Speed;
    
    public Player() {
        this.setBounds(new Rectangle (16,16));
    }
    
    public boolean isSameLayerAs(Component component) {
        
         if (JLayeredPane.getLayer(this) == application.Layer.getLayer(component) + 1) { 
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
    }
    
    public void movePlayer() {
        
        theLayer layer = application.Layer;

        Component ObjectAbove = layer.getComponentAt(this.getLocation().x + 8, this.getLocation().y + 14);
        
        
        
        if (ObjectAbove == null || (!isSameLayerAs(ObjectAbove) && this.getBounds().intersects(ObjectAbove.getBounds()))) {
            moveUp();
        }
        else if (ObjectAbove == null || (!isSameLayerAs(ObjectAbove) && !this.getBounds().intersects(ObjectAbove.getBounds()))) {
            moveUp();
        }
        layer.setLayer(this, ((this.getLocation().y) / 16) + 1);
    }
}
```

The player is 16x16 pixels large.
In the MovePlayer() Method it compares the layer of the object above the player with the layer of the player. If the player intersects with the object and has the same layer as the object, the player cannot move up. The layer of an object is the y-position divided by 16. To get the Object above the player I tried using getComponentAt(), and it works just fine if I choose a location the player isn't at, like:

```
this.getLocation().y - 1
```

I however want the player to overlap the object a little bit.
[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUHZK.png)

So I tried `layer.getComponentAt(this.getLocation().x + 8, this.getLocation().y + 14);`

getComponentAt() however returns the player, because the player is also at this location (the player is 16x16 pixels large).

So my question:
Is there a way to find all the components at a specific location?

Comment: Create a logical model of your game using plain Java getter / setter classes.  It's much easier to detect collisions between logical objects, like java.awt.Rectangle instances.

Comment: Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions.